# What's the deal with the gap between a site hitting 100% commitment and going private beta?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Area 51 private betas automatic yet?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56575/are-area-51-private-betas-automatic-yet)

First, how long is this window between 100% commitment and private beta? Second, is there a some reason behind it (such as it's just a little window to maximize the number of private beta users)?

Comment: See [Are Area 51 private betas automatic yet?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56575/are-area-51-private-betas-automatic-yet/56595#56595)